# Unable to read the appsettings.json connection string using configuration manager from webapi .net 8.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an asp.net webapi using .net 8.0  framework and I have the code below
in my DBContext

This works fine when I put in the connection string directly

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=.;database=myDb;trusted_connection=true;");
    }
```

Here i stored the connection string in appsettings.json file and it does not work.
All I get is object not an instance

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Yoman"].ConnectionString);
    }
```

appsettings.json file looks like this

```
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
      },
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "Yoman": "server=xxxx;database=Tester;integrated security=true;multipleactiveresultsets=true;"
      }
    }
```

The only other thing I can think of is my DbContext class resides in a Data.Persisternce project but I added
the project as a reference from my point of entry MainAPI

Do you know what I may be doing wrong here why I can't read my connection string with ConfigurationManager?

Comment: As Kent Prince's answer said, just inject the dbcontext in Program.cs. Otherwise you need  add the appsetting.json which in MainApi project to Configration in Data.Persisternce project.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rewrite your implementation by injecting the dbContext in program.cs file

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Yoman");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

var app = builder.Build();
```

And you can clean your dbContext just like this

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public YourDbContext(DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

// Your DbSet properties...
}
```

Comment: Where did _configuration come from? I don't think I have that in my code.

Comment: it was an oversight, changes have been made